# What is the casting order of operations in arithmetics in c++?

Tags: c++, types, casting, arithmetic-expressions

Why does

1. `result = static_cast<double>(1 / (i+1))`

return `int` in C++ and why does

2. `result = 1 / (i+static_cast<double>(1))`

return `double`? Specifically why is casting after the `+`-operation sufficient to produce a `double`. Why is it not required before the `+` or in the numerator as well? Is `static_cast` the preferred way of casting?

**Code:**

```
double harmonic(int n) {
  double result = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result += 1 / static_cast<double>(i+1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as "casting order" because the type of an expression depends on its operands. Put it simply, if a binary arithmetic operator accepts two operands of different types then the smaller type will be implicitly converted to the wider type

In `result = static_cast<double>(1 / (i+1))` it's parsed like this

- `i + 1` is an `int` expression since both `i` and `1` are of type `int`
- `1 / (i + 1)` returns int for the same reason
- Then the result of `1 / (i + 1)`, which is an `int`, is statically cast to `double`

OTOH in `result = 1 / (i+static_cast<double>(1))` it's like this

- `1` is cast to `double`
- `i + static_cast<double>(1)` returns `double` because `i` is upconverted to `double` due to the higher rank of the other operand
- `1 / (i+static_cast<double>(1))` is a `double` expression for the same reason. It's also a floating-point division instead of an integer division like in the other case

But don't cast like that. It's better to do `1 / (i + 1.0)` or `1.0 / (i + 1)` instead

The complete rule is like this

> - If either operand has scoped enumeration type, no conversion is performed: the other operand and the return type must have the same type
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `long double`, the other operand is converted to `long double`
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other operand is converted to `double`
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, the other operand is converted to `float`
> - Otherwise, the operand has integer type (because `bool`, `char`, `char8_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, and unscoped enumeration were promoted at this point) and integral conversions are applied to produce the common type, as follows:
>
>   - If both operands are signed or both are unsigned, the operand with lesser conversion rank is converted to the operand with the greater integer conversion rank
>   - Otherwise, if the unsigned operand's *conversion rank* is greater or equal to the conversion rank of the signed operand, the signed operand is converted to the unsigned operand's type.
>   - Otherwise, if the signed operand's type can represent all values of the unsigned operand, the unsigned operand is converted to the signed operand's type
>   - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned counterpart of the signed operand's type.
>
> The *conversion rank* above increases in order `bool`, `signed char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`. The rank of any unsigned type is equal to the rank of the corresponding signed type. The rank of `char` is equal to the rank of `signed char` and `unsigned char`. The ranks of `char8_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, and `wchar_t` are equal to the ranks of their underlying types.
>
> [Arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Comment: Great, thanks! This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I found the trick with 1.0 especially useful!

Answer (score 1):

```
static_cast<double>(1 / (i+1));
```

First, `1 / (i+1)` get evaluate. Because 1 is an `int` and `i+1` is an `int`, so this is integer division, so `1/(i+1)` is an `int`. The result is then typecast into a `double`. So technically, `static_cast<double>(1 / (i+1));` returns a `double`, but the result is lost because `1/(i+1)` is integer division

```
result += 1 / static_cast<double>(i+1);
```

Now becuase `static_cast<double>(i+1)` is a double, `1 / static_cast<double>(i+1);` is now floating point divison, thus `1 / static_cast<double>(i+1);` is a `double`

Comment: And, of course, `1.0 /(i + 1)` is even better.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of [Integer Divison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)

You can use this code to see, that it actually returns a double. However, due to integer division, it will always be zero (or nan).

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    cout << typeid(static_cast<double>(1 / (i+1))).name() << "\n"; // d for double
    return 0;
}
```

You can circumvent integer division, by not dividing two integers. Therefor it is enough if one of them is a double.

`int + double == double`
`double + int == double`
`int / double == double`
`double / int == double`

So you can see, it is enough to only cast one summand to double, in order to turn the whole expression into a double, which is not always zero.